# Jquery change the Element Order

Tags: jquery, html

How can I move each label in front of the input element they're next to using jQuery?

```
<div class="input select classCheckBox">
    <label for="checkboxId">classCheckBoxs</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="checkboxId" value="" name="checkboxName" />
    <br /> 
    <div class="classCheckBox"> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxId24" value="1" name="checkboxName[]" />
        <label for="checkboxId24">1 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="classCheckBox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxId25" value="2" name="checkboxName[]" />
        <label for="checkboxId25">2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="classCheckBox"> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxId26" value="3" name="checkboxName[]" />
        <label for="checkboxId26">3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="classCheckBox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxId27" value="4" name="checkboxName[]" />
        <label for="checkboxId27">4</label>
    </div>
    <div class="classCheckBox"> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxId28" value="5" name="checkboxName[]" />
        <label for="checkboxId28">5</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$('.select .classCheckBox label').each(function() {
  $(this).insertBefore( $(this).prev('input') );
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/437/)**

---

#### A little explain

- `$('.select .classCheckBox label')` select each `label` within each `.classCheckBox`
- `$(this)` within loop point to `label`
- `.insertBefore()` insert any element before the matched element that passed as argument
- `$(this).prev('input')` points the `input` before `label`
- so,  `$(this).insertBefore( $(this).prev('input') )` will insert each `label` before its previous `input`

---

**Related refs:**

- [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore)
- [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev)
- [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each)

---

#### Alternate ways:

```
$('.select .classCheckBox input').each(function() {
  $(this).insertAfter( $(this).next('label') );
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/438/)**

**OR**

```
$('.select .classCheckBox input').each(function() {
  $(this).before( $(this).next('label') );
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/442/)**