# html jquery move items from listbox to other listbox then move items up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listbox

I have listbox and I can move items to another listbox with this code

```
$().ready(function() {  
   $('#add').click(function() {  
    return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');  
   });  
   $('#remove').click(function() {  
    return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');  
   });  
  });

<select multiple="multiple" name="listbox1" id="select1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" id="add">&gt;&gt;</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="remove">&lt;&lt;</a>
<select multiple="multiple" name="listbox2" id="select2"></select>
```

With the code above I can move items from listbox1 to listbox2 and everything works fine.

I need to move items in listbox2 up and down

I googled and found that javascript code but I don't know how I can use it for listbox2 only

https://jsfiddle.net/m0f757wh/

Comment: The code in your question doesn't match that in the jsFiddle...?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m0f757wh/ that is the new code that I want to add it to my code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Refer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183401/jquery-change-the-element-order)

I just added event listeners to the buttons and followed the above post. I think the code is self-explanatory. Let me know if you're confused.

```js
$().ready(function() {
  $('#add').click(function() {
    return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');
  });
  
  $('#remove').click(function() {
    return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');
  });
  
  let $select1 = $('#select1');
  let $select2 = $('#select2');
  
  $('#up1').click(function () {
    let $selected = $select1.find('option:selected');
    $selected.insertBefore($selected.prev());
  });
  
  $('#down1').click(function () {
    let $selected = $select1.find('option:selected');
    $selected.insertAfter($selected.next());
  });
  
  $('#up2').click(function () {
    let $selected = $select2.find('option:selected');
    $selected.insertBefore($selected.prev());
  });
  
  $('#down2').click(function () {
    let $selected = $select2.find('option:selected');
    $selected.insertAfter($selected.next());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select multiple="multiple" name="listbox1" id="select1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" id="add">&gt;&gt;</a><br/>
      <a href="#" id="remove">&lt;&lt;</a>
      <select multiple="multiple" name="listbox2" id="select2"></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="up1">&uarr;</button>
      <button id="down1">&darr;</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="up2">&uarr;</button>
      <button id="down2">&darr;</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```