# Reorganize items with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I should find a way to reorganize the elements via jquery depending on the class that have or in each row composed of 3 elements there should be only one customBackgroundViewDue.

I have a table consisting of 12 elements and each row can hold a maximum of 3, when I reorganize the click depending on the category obviously does not take into account the different sizes and then organizes them randomly. I would need a way to organize them either by category (but up to here I can) and by spacing so each row must have 2 blocks with 1x size and 1 block with 2x size.
This is my code:

```
<div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="customAllBlockViewHome customBackgroundViewUno panificazione" style="background-image: url('http://demo.webpreview.cloud/mastermartini/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/892H2RCZ3Tf6gH3xSRP-275x244_center_center.jpg');">
  <div class="customTextAndIconViewHome">
    <div class="customIconViewHome">

    </div>
    <div class="customTextViewHome">
      Prova 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
        </div>


        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-12">

<div class="customAllBlockViewHome customBackgroundViewDue" style="background-image: url('http://demo.webpreview.cloud/mastermartini/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/704Mo04I0iSn1OvKLIS-275x244_center_center.jpg');">
  <div class="customTextAndIconViewHome">
    <div class="customIconViewHome">

    </div>
    <div class="customTextViewHome">
      Prova 5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
        </div>


        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="customAllBlockViewHome customBackgroundViewUno laboratori" style="background-image: url('http://demo.webpreview.cloud/mastermartini/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/892H2RCZ3Tf6gH3xSRP-275x244_center_center.jpg');">
  <div class="customTextAndIconViewHome">
    <div class="customIconViewHome">

    </div>
    <div class="customTextViewHome">
      Prova 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
        </div>


        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-12">

<div class="customAllBlockViewHome customBackgroundViewDue" style="background-image: url('http://demo.webpreview.cloud/mastermartini/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/9171zU8RKgk5VolazgI-275x244_center_center.jpg');">
  <div class="customTextAndIconViewHome">
    <div class="customIconViewHome">

    </div>
    <div class="customTextViewHome">
      Prova 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
        </div>
```

Has anyone already done something like that and could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What  have you tried yourself to create this?

Comment: I can not use very well jquery I tried a lot and the thing that came closest was this, but in my case it's not good (trying it with my variables of course) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183401/jquery-change-the-element-order

Comment: You question is not clear about what you want to achieve, can you give us more details?

Comment: I specified better in the text above. That's better?